# TFS SonarQube Extension is not sending comments to pull requests for JS files

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

I'm using Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 with [SonarQube extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube).

It's commenting to pull requests for `.cs` files but not commenting on JavaScript (`jsx`) files. When I check the report on the dashboard I can see comments for JS files, so it means, the scanner is analyzing JS files correctly but I couldn't understand why it's not sending comments to pull request.

How can I set it up to command for JS files too?

UPDATE: This is my build definition which linked to pull requests:

```
1) SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis (new)
2) Visual Studio Build (solution of our project)
3) npm install
4) npm run build
5) SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis (new)
```

As you see there are 2 different projects in the same folder. One of them is .NET project (step 2), another one is a NodeJS project (step 3-4).

Comment: Just to clarify: let's say I did modifications on 1 cs file and 1 JS file on same pull request. There are comments on `.cs` file but not on `jsx` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PR decoration in TFS/VSTS (i.e. adding comments and updating the status of a PR) used to be supported only for projects built with the Scanner for MSBuild, and with quite some limitations (what you are experiencing is probably one of them).

As a consequence, the support of PR decoration has been removed in the latest version of the TFS/VSTS extension.

We are now working on a proper support of PR decoration, that will work for any project (.NET, Java, JS, ...etc). We are planning to roll this out first on SonarCloud (using the [SonarCloud VSTS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarcloud)), and in a couple of month on SonarQube (using the [SonarQube TFS/VSTS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube)).

Comment: Hello Fabrice, thanks for your answer. Can you please clarify this : "supported only for projects built with the Scanner for MSBuild". What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Previous versions of the SonarQube TFS/VSTS extension was able to decorate pull requests only when the "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis" task was used, so by definition for .NET solutions only. You can read more at https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/SonarQube+Extension+3.0#SonarQubeExtension3.0-PullRequestcommenting

Comment: Hi @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam This might not be the correct place to ask, but do you have any ETA regarding the re-implementation of this feature for the TFS/VSTS extension?
I've tried looking at open issues on the github page, but couldn't find any related to this.

Comment: For SonarCloud, it's already available in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarcloud. For SonarQube, this will come in the upcoming months.